# FTPS certificate email address has different domain than the Organization name

Tags: ftp, ssl, certificate, ftps

Wondering if this should be of any concern. We received a FTPS ip which is SSL enabled. (This is not SFTP). Filezilla - the FTP client shows a certificate where the organization name say 'XYZ Inc' and the Email: is someone@pqr.com

At XYZ Inc there employees use XXXX@xyz.com and XXXX@xyz.net so while looking at the certificate I would expect the Email field to be anyone@xyz.com.

Is this a security concern ?

Comment: Contact `pqr` and ask them about that fact, but you should check the CN of the certificate matches the server name you are connecting to. I think that filezilla would refuse to connect if that info is not correct.

Comment: My guess is that the person identified on the certificate works for some outsourced IT group.  I don't think it's unusual to have a technical contact that doesn't match the domain but until you ask either company why, you won't know for sure.